# Molecular orbital notation

Tags: notation, orbitals, molecules, cold-atoms, term-symbols

[image]

I'm reading about papers about atom-ion interaction. There are some states as showned above.
The notations of the states look like molecular orbital since $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ is usually used in orbital hybridization to denote the different alignments of wavefunctions.
But the letters before $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$  and the superscripts are confusing me.

What are the letters (both lower and upper case) and all the superscript (numbers and +)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [molecular term symbol notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_term_symbol). Large greek letters are used because this labels the whole electronic state, and not just a one-electron orbital for which small greek letters are used. The roman alphabet letters are just enumerating the states, where $X^1$ is the singlet ground state, followed by $A^1,B^1,C^1$... for the excited states of same multiplicity as they are observed in the experiment. The small roman letters $a^3,b^3,c^3,...$  are used to enumerate excited states of different multiplicity to the ground state, in this case triplets. One should also note that these roman letters are not referring to irreducible representations.

See also [Why is there no Sigma-minus ground state for molecular hydrogen ion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329787/165488)

Comment: Thank you so much. Mostly I understand it. Are ABC or abc sorted by their energy?

Comment: @HanBao Yes, they should be. The labels are usually according to the energy of peaks in the experiment. But this is not without its problems, since experiments can miss states that are dark with respect to the transition that is measured. This can lead to different labeling in other papers based on measurement that have other selection rules. And it can make it difficult to align experiment with theory, since theory typically predicts all states, including the dark ones. These details depend on the particular papers but it is a good idea to keep these points in mind to avoid confusion.

Comment: Get it. Thanks for your help.